# Configure hugo to generate site from DB content

Tags: hugo

Is there a plugin or something in Hugo that allows hugo to read content from DB and generate site, rather than reading data from markdown/data files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of the box, Hugo only generates `HTML` (or `XML`, or `JSON`) representations of your Markdown files. There's something in Hugo's philosophy that says that reproducible builds take precedence over other things — I don't know where I've seen, but I have seen it at some point, when I was looking for the same thing you are.

But there are some ways to get you closer to that.

### `transform.unmarshall`

[`transform.unmarshal`](https://gohugo.io/functions/transform.unmarshal/) parses `JSON`, `TOML`, `YAML`, `XML`, or `CSV` resources and converts them to maps or arrays. But you still need a local file to use it.

One thing that you could do is to incroporate this into your build workflow and *before* you generate your site with Hugo, you would add a step to grab the data and write it to a local file in one of those formats.

### `resources.GetRemote`

[`resources.GetRemote`](https://gohugo.io/hugo-pipes/introduction/#get-resource-with-resourcesget-and-resourcesgetremote) makes an `HTTP` request to a remote URL, and has recently been added to Hugo.

This way, you wouldn't need to have a new step in the build process to grab, format, and write data to the disk; you would instead, add some logic in your templates to grab the data from a URL. Of course, you need that HTTP endpoint, so you still need some sort of API available.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrei!

Given that Hugo supports `resources.GetRemote`, I don't see allowing DB integration violates anything new wrt the principal "reproducible builds". I assume it's a feature waiting to be implemented by someone.

Comment: The point of that was that whenever you build your site, you know exactly what you get, because you have your content (markdown source files) right there. Adding data from an external source can take that away. I'm not fully sold on that take and I was actually surprised when I saw they have added `resource.GetRemote`.